# Maven deploy the EAR as an exploded archive to the app server

Tags: maven-3, jboss7.x

Is there a way to deploy the EAR as an exploded archive to the app server ex. JBoss AS7 in Maven?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After some research found the way to handle this.

In the ear project pom.xml add the following pluig-in

```
<plugin>
    <version>2.8</version>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <configuration>
        <unpackTypes>rar,war,ejb</unpackTypes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

- In the maven goal set **clean package**
- Then copy the exploded folder which is in the target to jboss deployment folder.
- Add .ear extension into the exploded archive

Once this is done,

- Add **auto-deploy-exploded="true"** in the **standalone.xml** **deployment-scanner** element
- When start the Jboss it will auto deploy the exploded ear

Now you can add any static files or java class which will get auto deployed

However, This is not reccommedned in the production environment.

Best practice is,

In the meven goal set the **clean package** and it will generate the .ear archive file. You can either copy in to the deployment folder or using maven **jboss-as:deploy** plugin you can deploy it automatically.

Comment: For completness, there it is also possible to unpack some modules only, by using the `<unpack>true</unpack>` option, see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/unpacking-a-module.html